options loading lag when hiding and showing options in a select
first click on select displays bad

second click on select displays good

$(document).on("click", "#edit_afpDetalle_mes", function () {
        actualizarSelectsMes('#edit_tabla_afp_detalle');
    });
 
    $(document).on("click", "#btnEliminarFilaEdit", function () {
        eliminarFila(this);
    });

function actualizarSelectsMes(id_input) {
    // Obtener todos los meses seleccionados en las filas existentes
    var mesesSeleccionados = [];
    document.querySelectorAll(id_input + ' tbody select').forEach(function (select) {
        if (select.value !== '') {
            mesesSeleccionados.push(select.value);
        }
    });
 
    // Actualizar cada select en la tabla
    document.querySelectorAll(id_input).forEach(function (select) {
        select.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(function (option) {
            // Si la opción está seleccionada en otro select, ocultarla
            if (mesesSeleccionados.includes(option.value) && option.value !== select.value) {
                option.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                option.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    });
}

The select should show the options as in the second image, but a lag occurs first, all the options are shown and the selected ones are quickly hidden.

That lag will persist until you've tied the loading of your options to something other than click. If you're only starting to load the options when your user clicks to see them... you will almost certainly notice the lag when your application is at load -- or if it has transit time... etc.
For a more consistent experience for these options, consider loading this data when the document is ready. You could also keep handlers for when any of the options are selected for subsequent updates.

@americanfalvour The options are 12 that are created in the html, but if I have option 1 and 2 selected, they should no longer be displayed, so add an event to verify which options are selected and add display none and the remaining display block.
